# Trying to use combination of CSS, jQuery and HTML to create a repeatable mouseenter/mouseleave function

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, repeat

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.display').mouseenter(function() {
         $(this).fadeTo('fast',0);
    });
    $('.display').mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
```

My CSS:

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}

.display {
    padding:10px;
}

.bluespot {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}

.redspot {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class='display'><div class='bluespot'></div></div>
    <div class='display'><div class='redspot'></div></div>
</div>
```

**Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/andrewtanner/ZyEKz/1/**

What I want to do is repeat these red and blue CSS classes as a background, preferably relative to the users screen. I could repeat the classes over and over by simply pasting more code in but that doesn't seem particular efficient and it will only ever be to an absolute value. Is there any way of repeating CSS when it's not an image background, i.e the background-repeat element?

Comment: What you want is repeating your html with javascript, don't you ?

Comment: Pretty much, if there's no CSS alternative (which I'm guessing there isn't). Someone on my Facebook suggested PHP?

Comment: Indeed there is no CSS alternative. PHP is not a good choice as it has nothing to do with screen width and height of a user. I will suggest you something as an answer.

Comment: Did any of those answers solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is adding dynamicly your "spots" divs with javascript. This is the main idea :

- You get the width and height of the screen
- You divide both of them by the width and height of a spot
- You loop over the number of spots in height
- Inside this loop you loop again with number of spots in width

Maybe it is better watching it in action with this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyEKz/8/)**

This are the loops :

```
// spots are 30x30 squares
// how much can we put in height ? 
number_h = parseInt(window_h / 30);
// in width
number_w = parseInt(window_w / 30);

for(var h_it = 0; h_it < number_h; h_it++)
{
    for(var w_it = 0; w_it < number_w; w_it++)
    {
        // to make one blue, one red, one blue... 
        // and change the order the next line
        if(w_it%2 === h_it%2) {
            $('<div class="display"><div class="bluespot"></div></div>')
                .appendTo('#container');
        } else {
            $('<div class="display"><div class="redspot"></div></div>')
                .appendTo('#container');
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this might not be perfect, but at least you got the idea.

This is a more sophisticated Fiddle with centered container and refresh on windows resize event : 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZyEKz/10/

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I'm gonna analyse the hell out of that code so I make sure I understand it. Really appreciate that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had come up with a method using cloning which I was firing across on Twitter as well (which is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bmgh1985/LfHC8 - edit:Must put code...)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numberOfClones = 7;
    var el = $('.display');
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfClones; i++) {
        var newEl = el.clone();
        $('.display').append(newEl);

}
```

but that solution from Brewal works well and would work better in most cases.

Comment: You can check it out here in action http://www.andrewtanner.me/ Had a good look over your code and it makes sense but I will re-write it myself with a view to properly understanding it.